# Realizar função a cada determinado periodo de tempo

Tags: c, funções

ola eu gostaria de implementar uma funcao em meu programa que realiza uma tarefa a cada determinado periodo de tempo tendo esse codigo como exemplo algo assim que eu estou querendo

```
void main(){
    while(1){
        if(passou 5 minutos){
            chama_funcao();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ja ouviu falar sobre threads?

Answer (score 1):

Pensei algo como um contador, e colocando o tempo de acordo com o valor que a variável `a` sofre um incremento.
A função`sleep();` funciona basicamente como um temporizador, assim, essa função faz uma verificação a cada 1 segundo.

O código fica basicamente assim :

```
 void main(){
        int a = 0;
        while(1){
            a++;
            if(passou 5 minutos){
                chama_funcao();
            }
            sleep(1);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma das maneiras de se fazer isso é com o `time()` do `time.h`:

```
#include <time.h>
```

Código:

```
time_t tempoInicial;
time_t tempoAtual;
tempoInicial = time(NULL);
while (1){
    tempoAtual = time(NULL);
    if (tempoAtual / 60 > tempoInicial / 60 + 5){
        tempoInicial = time(NULL);
        //O que estiver aqui, será executado de 5 em 5 minutos
    }
}
```